# Append string to output

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following code in wordpress :

```
foreach($out as $outs)
{

    $store = $outs->store; 
    $latv = $outs->lat;
    $lngv = $outs->lng;
    $tagv = "#filter-list-".$outs->fax;


    $posts[] = array('latitude'=> $latv, 'longitude'=> $lngv, 'area'=>$tagv, 'content'=> $store);
}
```

I want to append **#filter-list-** .But the above code only output **#filter-list-**.It is not appending `$outs->fax`. I have tried variables of variables.But by doing this, it is taking null value.

So how can I append **#filter-list-** ?

Comment: In your loop, let's dump out the `$outs->fax`, check, is it has any value.

Comment: Test if $outs->fax is null

Comment: Genius :) How silly am I :) There were no value and I was trying since half n hour :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe $outs->fax is empty